# Check Battery Status in a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, power-management

I'm trying to find a way to check the battery status on a batch file, i.e stop the execution of the script if the laptop is running on battery. I'm trying with the `poercfg` command with no results.

All I need is Something like that but in a batch file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ acpi -a | grep "off-line" eq 0 ]; 
   then echo "plug your laptop and run it again"
   exit 1
fi
```

What can I use?

Comment: What OS are you on? You say "batch file" in the title which is a windows thing then have an example in bash which is usually a Linux thing. You need to provide some more clues to get an accurate answer!

Comment: I need this on a windows machine

Comment: @kerio: Then the question is *not* about [tag:bash]. I'll remove that tag; add it back if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux you can get this information from `/proc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -q discharging /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state; then
   echo "plug your laptop and run it again"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: On my laptops, the path is /sys/class/power_supply/. There will typically be two subfolders (but naming might differ), but a file named `type` will say either "Mains" or "Battery". The file `online` in a Mains type directory is 1 if you're plugged in. However, my desktop, which has both mains and a UPS "battery" (which my XFCE desktop shows status for) doesn't have neither folder, so there must be some third method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Rob Vanderwoude's script](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battrun_xp.txt) might work. As expected it's more work. It looks like it's using some WMI information.

Comment: Since he's tagged it "bash", and gives an idea in bash script, I doubt using WMI is feasible...

Comment: @carlpett: The OP also titled it "batch file" so the confusion is understandable. Cygwin?

Comment: @carlpeet read the final line: ```All I need is Something like that but in a batch file:```He's giving a *nix example of something he wants to do with a batch file.

Comment: Yes Caley, This is exactly that's I'm looking for, I'll be able to write it on linux, but I'm looking for a solution on Windows.

Comment: Hmm The Rob Vandewoulde's script do not feet with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can using $? to get the last return status of grep.
I think this will work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
acpi -a | grep "off-line"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
   then echo "plug your laptop and run it again"
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

```
@echo off
wmic Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus | find "2" > nul
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
  echo Not running on AC, exiting
  exit /B
)
echo running on AC, continuing execution
```

I have stolen wmic query from Rob's script referenced by Caley

Comment: Is this information present in events so it can be used in task scheduler. I.e send me an email when on battery power.

Comment: @Arthor No it's not logged in event log. But if you search SO you'll find quite a few workarounds/powershell/vbs code

Answer (score 0):

```
$designCap = Get-WmiObject -Class "BatteryStaticData" -Namespace "ROOT\WMI" |
Group-Object -Property InstanceName -AsHashTable -AsString

Get-CimInstance -Class "BatteryFullChargedCapacity" -Namespace "ROOT\WMI" |
Select-Object -Property InstanceName, FullChargedCapacity, DesignedCapacity, Percent |
ForEach-Object {
$_.DesignedCapacity = $designCap[$_.InstanceName].DesignedCapacity
$_.Percent = [Math]::Round( ( $_.FullChargedCapacity*100/$_.DesignedCapacity),2)
$_
}
```

Output

```
   InstanceName     FullChargedCapacity DesignedCapacity Percent
    ------------     ------------------- ---------------- -------
    ACPI\PNP0C0A\1_0               78455            95008   82,58
```